# Convergence of improper integral $\int_0^{1} x^{\alpha -1} e^{-x} dx$

Tags: calculus

For which values of $\alpha$ does this integral converge?

$\int_0^{1} x^{\alpha -1} e^{-x} dx$

The only problematic point is $0$ , so I tried comparing this with $x^{p} $ for some $p<1$ there. The limit is $0$ for every $p,\alpha$ such that $\alpha-p-1>0$ , so I guess that this converges for every $\alpha>1$ . 
It is obvious that for $\alpha=1 $ the integral diverges.

But, how can I show that the integral diverges for every $\alpha<1 $ ?

Thanks !

Comment: It is not obvious to me that "for $\alpha = 1$ the integral diverges."  $\int_0^1e^{-x}\,dx \approx 0.63$

Comment: In fact, $\alpha = 0$ is the point where it becomes divergent.

Comment: It certainly converges if $\alpha>0$ since $x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x} \leq  x^{\alpha-1}$ and that converges for $\alpha-1 > -1$.

Answer (score 4):

We have
$$x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}\sim_0 x^{\alpha-1}$$
and the integral
$$\int_0^1 x^{\alpha-1}dx$$
is convergent if and only if $1-\alpha<1\iff\alpha>0.$
so the given integral is convergent iff $\alpha>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Looking at [Incomplete Gamma Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) can be informative.

Comment: short and sweet Arash +1

Answer (score 0):

The integral diverges for every $\alpha \le 0$, and converges if $\alpha\gt 0$.

For the convergence when $\alpha\gt 0$, note that $0\le e^{-x}\le 1$ in our interval. And if $\alpha\gt 0$ then $\alpha-1 \gt -1$, and therefore we have convergence.

Now we look at the case $\alpha\le 0$. 
Note that for $x$ between $0$ and $1$, we have $e^x\le e$ and therefore $e^{-x}\ge \frac{1}{e}$. Thus, for $\alpha\le0$, we have $x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}\ge \frac{e}{x}$, but $\int_0^1 \frac{x}{e}\,dx$ diverges.